# What's the best way to get HTable handle of HBase?

Tags: apache, hbase

One way is directly call the HTable constructor, another is to call the getTable method from a HConnection.  The second option requires the HConnection to be "unmanaged", which is not very good for me because my process will have many threads accessing HBase.  I don't want to re-invent the wheel to manage the HConnections on my own.

Thanks for your help.

[Updates]: 
We are stuck with 0.98.6, so ConnectionFactory is not available.

I found the bellow jira suggesting to create an "unmanaged" connection and use a single ExecuteService to create HTable. Why can't we simply use the getTable method of the unmanaged connection to get HTable?  Is that because of HTable is not thread safe?
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-7463

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im stuck with old versions (<0.94.11) in which you can still use `HTablePool` but since it has been deprecated by [HBASE-6580](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6580) I think requests from HTables to the RS are now automatically pooled by providing an `ExecutorService`:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf, executor);
Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("mytable"));
try {
    table.get(...);
    ...
} finally {
    table.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

> I've been unable to find any good examples/docs about it, so please notice this is untested code which may not work as expected.

For more information you can take a look to the ConnectionFactory documentation & to the JIRA issue:
https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/ConnectionFactory.html
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6580

**Update**, since you're using 0.98.6 and ConnectionFactory is not available you can use HConnectionManager instead:

```
HConnection connection = HConnectionManager.createConnection(config); // You can also provide an ExecutorService if you want to override the default one. HConnection is thread safe.
HTableInterface table = connection.getTable("table1");
try {
  // Use the table as needed, for a single operation and a single thread
} finally {
  table.close();
  connection.close();
}
```

HTable is not thread safe so you must make sure you always get a new instance (it's a lightweight process) with `HTableInterface table = connection.getTable("table1")` and close it afterwards with `table.close()`.

The flow would be:

- 1. Start your process
- 2. Initialize your HConnection
- 3. Each thread:
- 3.1 Gets a table from your HConnection
- 3.2 Writes/reads from the table
- 3.3 Closes the table
- 4. Close your HConnection when your process ends

HConnectionManager: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HConnectionManager.html#createConnection(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)

HTable: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Forgot to mention we are stuck with 0.98.6 so there is no ConnectionFactory.  I've updated my question and added with another option to choose from.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I hope it's more clear now :)